# Dynamics CRM + Hide a button based on security role

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to hide a button on the ribbon for all users except System Admin and I do not want to write javascript to check the security role of the logged in users. Is there any out-of-box way I can achieve this?

Also is there any entity that only admin has access to which I can use to hide show the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this without code.

One option is using `MiscellaneousPrivilgeRule` under display rules and making sure to pick some privilege like `Publish Duplicate Detection Rules` which may not be given to non-Admin roles.

[image]

[image]

[Read more](https://goutamdascrm.wordpress.com/2020/01/06/show-hide-ribbon-button-based-on-security-role-without-writing-code-in-dynamics-365-ce/)

There’s no OOB entity for that purpose, you can identify one in your system or create a dummy entity for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you..was looking for the same. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try this option.

1. Create a Custom Entity (Custom Button Privelege)
2. By default only Sys Admin/Cust role will have Privelege to do CRUD operation.
3. In the custom button -> Display Rule. Set a Entity Privelege Rule based on the custom entity.
4. Now the button will be visible only for the Admin users & will be hidden for other users.

Similarly we can modify the security role for others as well.